# Not able to remove cypress proxy settings

Tags: npm, cypress

I  configured cypress proxy using :

```
npm config set proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
```

But when I tried npm config rm proxy, proxy is not getting removed from Cypress Proxy Settings.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had to edit .npmrc file in home directory and comment out the line with proxy setting:

```
#proxy=http://proxy.my.tld:8080/
```